# Based on selection is it possible to change value axis

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a requirement i.e based on the tree view check box selection the value axis need to update.I am using 4 check boxes with 4 value axis.when ever I check the first item corresponding value axis should be changed .3 other axis should in invisible state.

Here I tried with some of the code and updated .

Code:

```
 <div id="treeview"></div>
  <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div class="chart-wrapper">
                <div id="chart"></div>
            </div>
       </div> 

 var valueAxes = [
       { name: "KM",visible:false,
        title: { text: "KM" ,visible:false}
                                },
                              { name: "Miles Per Gallon",
                                    title: { text: "Miles Per Gallon" }
                                },

                            {
                                name: "Miles",

                                title: { text: "Miles " }
                            },

                            {
                                name: "liters per 100km", 
                                title: { text: "liters per 100km" }
                            }
                        ];
    function createChart() {
                        $("#chart").kendoChart({

                            legend: {
                                position: "top"
                            },
                            series: [{
                                type: "column",
                                data: [20, 40, 45, 30, 50],
                                stack: true,
                                name: "on battery",
                                color: "#003c72"
                            }, {
                                type: "column",
                                data: [20, 30, 35, 35, 40],
                                stack: true,
                                name: "on gas",
                                color: "#0399d4"
                            }, {
                                type: "area",
                                data: [30, 38, 40, 32, 42],
                                name: "mpg",
                                color: "#642381" 

                            }, {
                                type: "area",
                                data: [7.8, 6.2, 5.9, 7.4, 5.6],
                                name: "l/100 km",
                                color: "#e5388a" 

                            }],
                            valueAxes:valueAxes,                      
                            categoryAxis: {
                                categories: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],

                                axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10]
                            }

                        });
                    }

        $(document).ready(function() {    
            createChart();     
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
              checkboxes: {
               checkChildren: true
                },
          dataSource: [{
            id: 1,
            text: "Value axis",
            expanded: true,
            items: [{
                id: 2,
                text: "KM"  
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                text: "Miles Per Gallon" 
            },
              {
                id: 4,
                text: "Miles "   
            },
              {
                id: 5,
                text: "liters per 100km"  
            }]
        }]
    }).data("kendoTreeView");
    $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
        var checkedSeries = [];    
        $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function() {
          var nodeText =$(this).parent().parent().text();        
          $.each(valueAxes, function(index, valueAxes) {
             if (valueAxes.name == nodeText) {
              checkedSeries.push(valueAxes);
             checkedSeries.visible==="true";
             checkedSeries.title.visible===true;
                }
            });
        });    
        chart.options.valueAxes = checkedSeries;
        chart.refresh();
    });                     
    });
```

jsbin: [Value axis change](http://jsbin.com/eyibar/26/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , it is possible to bind and unbind value axis and series at a time.
Change your scripts like below

```
   var valueAxes = [
               {
                   name: "KM", labels: {
                       format: "{0}"
                   }, min: 0,
                   max: 9,


                   title: { text: "KM" }
               },
               {
                   name: "Miles Per Gallon", labels: {
                       format: "{0}%"
                   }, min: 0,
                   max: 5,


                   title: { text: "Miles Per Gallon" }
               },

              {
                  name: "Miles", labels: {
                      format: "{0}%"
                  },

                  title: { text: "Miles " }
              },

              {
                  name: "liters per 100km", min: 0,
                  max: 1,

                  title: { text: "liters per 100km" }
              }];

        var series = [{
            type: "column",
            axis: "KM",
            data: [20, 40, 45, 30, 50],
            stack: true,
            name: "KM",
            color: "#003c72"
        }, {
            type: "column",
            data: [20, 30, 35, 35, 40],
            axis: "Miles Per Gallon",
            stack: true,
            name: "Miles Per Gallon",
            color: "#0399d4"
        }, {
            type: "column",
            data: [30, 38, 40, 32, 42],
            axis: "Miles",
            name: "Miles",
            color: "#642381"

        }, {
            type: "column",
            axis: "liters per 100km",
            data: [7.8, 6.2, 5.9, 7.4, 5.6],
            name: "liters per 100km",
            color: "#e5388a"

        }];
        function createChart(inputValueAxes, inputSeries) {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({

                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                series: inputSeries,
                valueAxes: inputValueAxes,
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],

                    axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10]
                }

            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            createChart(valueAxes, series);
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true
                },
                dataSource: [{
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Value axis",
                    expanded: true,
                    items: [{
                        id: 2,
                        text: "KM"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        text: "Miles Per Gallon"
                    },
                      {
                          id: 4,
                          text: "Miles "
                      },
                      {
                          id: 5,
                          text: "liters per 100km"
                      }]
                }]
            }).data("kendoTreeView");

            $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
                var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                var checkedSeries = [];
                var checkedAxes = [];
                if ($("#treeview").find(":checked").length !== 0) {
                    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
                        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

                        $.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                            if (valueAxes.name == nodeText.trim()) {
                                checkedAxes.push(valueAxes);
                                checkedAxes.visible = true;
                            }
                        });

                        $.each(series, function (index, series) {
                            if (series.name == nodeText.trim()) {
                                checkedSeries.push(series);
                            }
                        });
                    });                    

                    createChart(checkedAxes, checkedSeries);
                }

                else {
                    createChart(checkedAxes, checkedSeries);
                }

            });
        });
```

Refer this http://jsbin.com/eyibar/49/edit

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, Intially i load all the chart axeses. Its working as you asked....

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/eyibar/37/edit

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <style>
            #chart { width: 600px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="treeview"></div>
        <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div class="chart-wrapper">
                <div id="chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var valueAxes = [
                {
                    name: "KM",
                    title: { text: "KM" }
                },
                {
                    name: "Miles Per Gallon",
                    title: { text: "Miles Per Gallon" }
                },

               {
                   name: "Miles",
                   title: { text: "Miles " }
               },

               {
                   name: "liters per 100km",
                   title: { text: "liters per 100km" }
               }];

            function createChart(valueAxes) {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({

                    legend: {
                        position: "top"
                    },
                    series: [{
                        type: "column",
                        data: [20, 40, 45, 30, 50],
                        stack: true,
                        name: "on battery",
                        color: "#003c72"
                    }, {
                        type: "column",
                        data: [20, 30, 35, 35, 40],
                        stack: true,
                        name: "on gas",
                        color: "#0399d4"
                    }, {
                        type: "area",
                        data: [30, 38, 40, 32, 42],
                        name: "mpg",
                        color: "#642381"

                    }, {
                        type: "area",
                        data: [7.8, 6.2, 5.9, 7.4, 5.6],
                        name: "l/100 km",
                        color: "#e5388a"

                    }],
                    valueAxes: valueAxes,
                    categoryAxis: {
                        categories: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],

                        axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10]
                    }

                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                createChart(valueAxes);
                $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    checkboxes: {
                        checkChildren: true
                    },
                    dataSource: [{
                        id: 1,
                        text: "Value axis",
                        expanded: true,
                        items: [{
                            id: 2,
                            text: "KM"
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            text: "Miles Per Gallon"
                        },
                          {
                              id: 4,
                              text: "Miles "
                          },
                          {
                              id: 5,
                              text: "liters per 100km"
                          }]
                    }]
                }).data("kendoTreeView");

                $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
                    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                    var checkedSeries = [];
                    if ($("#treeview").find(":checked").length != 0) {
                        $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
                            var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();
                            $.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                                if (valueAxes.name == nodeText.trim()) {
                                    checkedSeries.push(valueAxes);
                                    checkedSeries["visible"] = true;
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        createChart(checkedSeries);
                    }
                    else {
                        createChart(checkedSeries);
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hai, With the value axis its working .But is it possible to bind and unbind value axis and series at a time.here is the js fiddle I worked.  http://jsbin.com/eyibar/41/edit

Comment: Hai,I have another doubt in kendo stock chart when i select type column the navigator is not scrolling to till end can you suggest any answer and navigator type is changing like column or line is it possible to make type as area default. here is the js bin.http://jsbin.com/ilemel/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code in that I can able to bind and unbind the valueaxis by calling the creatChart(checkedAxes) function in if condition with length==-1,at that time the series is not updated.

```
$("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
              var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
              var checkedSeries = []; 
              var checkedAxes = [];
                if ($("#treeview").find(":checked").length !== -1){
                   $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
                   var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

                    $.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                           if (valueAxes.name == nodeText) {
                               checkedAxes.push(valueAxes);
                               checkedAxes.visible = true;
                           }
                     });

                   $.each(series, function (index, series) {
                       if (series.name == nodeText) {
                           checkedSeries.push(series);
                       }
                        });
                   });

                    chart.options.series = checkedSeries;
                    chart.options.valeAxes = checkedAxes;
                    chart.refresh();
                }
                    createChart(checkedAxes);
            });
```

but if I tried by without calling the creatChart(checkedAxes) function,the series binded to the chart are updated.

```
$("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
              var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
              var checkedSeries = []; 
              var checkedAxes = [];
                if ($("#treeview").find(":checked").length !== -1){
                   $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
                   var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

                    $.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                           if (valueAxes.name == nodeText) {
                               checkedAxes.push(valueAxes);
                               checkedAxes.visible = true;
                           }
                     });

                   $.each(series, function (index, series) {
                       if (series.name == nodeText) {
                           checkedSeries.push(series);
                       }
                        });
                   });

                    chart.options.series = checkedSeries;
                    chart.options.valeAxes = checkedAxes;
                    chart.refresh();
                }
            });
```

I didn't get the both scenarios at a time.sorry,hope you find the solution.

Cheers,
Happy Coding...